# Custom AuthenticationType and Elmah (C#)

Tags: c#, authentication, elmah

Im trying to restict access to my elmax.axd page.

The site does not use regular ASP.NET authentication, but instead a custom authentication.

Im wondering how I can get these to play together.

I try to add this in my `web.config`

[image]

But I only get a `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` error.

I know im logged in to the system:
[image]

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?